# Compare Clob to String value with JPA native query

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, repository, nativequery

i am trying to write a native Query on repository level so as to be able to filter the results. Below the property of my Entity (mapping to table Dummy):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DUMMY")
@Setter
@Getter
public class DummyEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID")
Integer id;
@Column(name = "NAME")
String name;
@Column(name = "PARTICIPANTS")
Clob participants;
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM DUMMY WHERE dbms_lob.instr(PARTICIPANTS,':username') > 0",nativeQuery = true)
List<DummyEntity> findByParticipant1(@Param("username") String username);
```

How can I achieve it?
Thank you in advance

Comment: What happens when you try your query? And something like JPQL "Select d from Dummy d where FUNCTION('dbms_lob.instr', d.participants, :username) > 0" might work depending on which JPA version you are using.

Comment: It was like :  List<DummyEntity> findByTimedeletedIsNullAndParticipantsLike(@Param("username") Clob likePattern);

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "PARTICIPANTS")
String participants;
```

If participants is a list, you could serialize it into a string using the ObjectMapper of Jackson

Comment: how to deserialize it?